# How to set quality of service within AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, qos

Does anyone knowing about set `qos class` in `AFNetworking`?

Because some of request in my app triggers time out, at the same time there is other operations of operation queue going on using network.

I want to set all networking request by `AFNetworking` to `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED`, it's seems the default value is `QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT`, how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`, which has the `qualityOfService` property.